# ActiveRecord Relation with scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

Using Rails 3.2/Ruby 1.9, for example I have the following classes:

```
class Foo
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar
  scope :active, where(:active=>true)
  # also tried
  # scope :active, lambda{where(:active=>true)}
  # scope :active, -> {where(:active=>true)}
end
```

Now if I have an instance of Foo (f), and I do `f.bars`, I get an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation as expected.  For some reason though when I do `f.bars.active`, I get undefined method `active` for the relation object (I'll buy this as the scope is on the `Bar` class).  I can do `f.bars.where(:active=>true)` no problem though.  I guess my questions are:

1. What is happening under the hood here?
2. How can I use the active scope to achieve the desired result?

Comment: The example above does work. My situation was my class had an error in it (silently failing) only discovered when I did Bar.active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must wrap the scope statements in a lambda before it will work correctly:

```
scope :active, -> { where(:active=>true) }
```

Comment: I'm accepting this because syntacticly this is correct for the original answer.